# What should I do to make my Raspberry Pi safe for SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi

OS: Raspbian

I want to be able to access my Raspberry Pi from the internet. However, Raspbian comes shipped with a default username and password, which means anyone can access it. I have changed the password.

Will changing the password give me the same level of security as SSH-ing on a normal linux system which you install from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are advices to secure your ssh connection:

- If you don't need to access your ssh server throw internet, allow only connections from your LAN or even better from specific IP
- If you need to access your ssh server throw internet, change your ssh port
- Don't use the root account to connect to your ssh server
- Use a private key to connect to your ssh server instead of password and disable connections with password
- Use an application like Fail2Ban to ban users (IP) which try to guess your password

Don't hesitate to make a quick search on the web about the previous points if you want details or ask in the comments.

Comment: What's the problem with accessing the pi with a root account?

Comment: It's not a problem, it's just less secure. If someone guess your password he will have a full access to your server.